# Is There is a way to get a Page Name from which Page it has been redirected in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three pages
1.index.html
2.navigate.html
3.lastpage.html

Index.html

```
<a href="lastpage.html">lastpage</a>
```

Navigate.html

```
<a href="lastpage.html">lastpage</a>
```

I need to get the page name in **Lastpage.html** from which page it is redirected in javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond other answers, you can always store some values (like source URL) in local storage (per session, or per client), `sessionStorage.setItem("source", "b.html");`.

Comment: Thank you but already i had lot of sessionstorage for login and others,so please give me jquery or javascript solutions

Comment: ... but you said you use it already, so some chunk of bytes are reserved anyway, and we are talking here about additional 100 character?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer)

Comment: This is for phonegap app so we can't use querystring plz tell me any other solution

Comment: @user1463105 - There is nothing in my answer about query strings. I think you mean this comment for the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
<a href="lastpage.html?page=navigate">lastpage</a>
```

And check query in JS - [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: This is for phonegap app so we can't use querystring plz tell me any other solution